# React render is messed

Tags: reactjs, frontend, jsx, tailwind-css, vite

[Current site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwDjd.png)

[How its supposed to render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPOQm.png)

I've used the code of a similar site I've done. The frontend is mostly copy-paste. So not sure how its messed up now.

Code for Navigation bar:

Navbar.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import { HiMenuAlt4 } from "react-icons/hi";
import { AiOutlineClose } from "react-icons/ai";

import logo from "../../images/logo.png";

const NavBarItem = ({ title, classprops }) => (
  <li className={`mx-4 cursor-pointer ${classprops}`}>{title}</li>
);

const Navbar = () => {
  const [toggleMenu, setToggleMenu] = React.useState(false);

  return (
    <nav className="w-full flex md:justify-center justify-between items-center p-4">
      <div className="md:flex-[0.5] flex-initial justify-center items-center">
        <img src={logo} alt="logo" className="w-32 cursor-pointer" />
      </div>
      <ul className="text-white md:flex hidden list-none flex-row justify-between items-center flex-initial">
        {["Market", "Exchange", "Tutorials", "Wallets"].map((item, index) => (
          <NavBarItem key={item + index} title={item} />
        ))}
        <li className="bg-[#2952e3] py-2 px-7 mx-4 rounded-full cursor-pointer hover:bg-[#2546bd]">
          Login
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div className="flex relative">
        {!toggleMenu && (
          <HiMenuAlt4 fontSize={28} className="text-white md:hidden cursor-pointer" onClick={() => setToggleMenu(true)} />
        )}
        {toggleMenu && (
          <AiOutlineClose fontSize={28} className="text-white md:hidden cursor-pointer" onClick={() => setToggleMenu(false)} />
        )}
        {toggleMenu && (
          <ul
            className="z-10 fixed -top-0 -right-2 p-3 w-[70vw] h-screen shadow-2xl md:hidden list-none
            flex flex-col justify-start items-end rounded-md blue-glassmorphism text-white animate-slide-in"
          >
            <li className="text-xl w-full my-2"><AiOutlineClose onClick={() => setToggleMenu(false)} /></li>
            {["Market", "Exchange", "Tutorials", "Wallets"].map(
              (item, index) => <NavBarItem key={item + index} title={item} classprops="my-2 text-lg" />,
            )}
          </ul>
        )}
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

Welcome.jsx

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { AiFillPlayCircle } from "react-icons/ai";
import { SiEthereum } from "react-icons/si";
import { BsInfoCircle } from "react-icons/bs";

import { TransactionContext } from "../context/TransactionContext";
import { shortenAddress } from "../utils/shortenAddress";
import { Loader } from ".";

const companyCommonStyles = "min-h-[70px] sm:px-0 px-2 sm:min-w-[120px] flex justify-center items-center border-[0.5px] border-gray-400 text-sm font-light text-white";

const Input = ({ placeholder, name, type, value, handleChange }) => (
  <input
    placeholder={placeholder}
    type={type}
    step="0.0001"
    value={value}
    onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, name)}
    className="my-2 w-full rounded-sm p-2 outline-none bg-transparent text-white border-none text-sm white-glassmorphism"
  />
);

const Welcome = () => {
  const { currentAccount, connectWallet, handleChange, sendTransaction, formData, isLoading } = useContext(TransactionContext);

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    const { addressTo, amount, keyword, message } = formData;

    e.preventDefault();

    if (!addressTo || !amount || !keyword || !message) return;

    sendTransaction();
  };


  return (
    <div className="flex w-full justify-center items-center">
      <div className="flex mf:flex-row flex-col items-start justify-between md:p-20 py-12 px-4">
        <div className="flex flex-1 justify-start items-start flex-col mf:mr-10">
          <h1 className="text-3xl sm:text-5xl text-white text-gradient py-1">
            Send Crypto <br /> across the world
          </h1>
          <p className="text-left mt-5 text-white font-light md:w-9/12 w-11/12 text-base">
            Explore the crypto world. Buy and sell cryptocurrencies easily on Krypto.
          </p>
          {!currentAccount && (
            <button
              type="button"
              onClick={connectWallet}
              className="flex flex-row justify-center items-center my-5 bg-[#2952e3] p-3 rounded-full cursor-pointer hover:bg-[#2546bd]"
            >
              <AiFillPlayCircle className="text-white mr-2" />
              <p className="text-white text-base font-semibold">
                Connect Wallet
              </p>
            </button>
          )}

          <div className="grid sm:grid-cols-3 grid-cols-2 w-full mt-10">
            <div className={`rounded-tl-2xl ${companyCommonStyles}`}>
              Reliability
            </div>
            <div className={companyCommonStyles}>Security</div>
            <div className={`sm:rounded-tr-2xl ${companyCommonStyles}`}>
              Ethereum
            </div>
            <div className={`sm:rounded-bl-2xl ${companyCommonStyles}`}>
              Web 3.0
            </div>
            <div className={companyCommonStyles}>Low Fees</div>
            <div className={`rounded-br-2xl ${companyCommonStyles}`}>
              Blockchain
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="flex flex-col flex-1 items-center justify-start w-full mf:mt-0 mt-10">
          <div className="p-3 flex justify-end items-start flex-col rounded-xl h-40 sm:w-72 w-full my-5 eth-card .white-glassmorphism ">
            <div className="flex justify-between flex-col w-full h-full">
              <div className="flex justify-between items-start">
                <div className="w-10 h-10 rounded-full border-2 border-white flex justify-center items-center">
                  <SiEthereum fontSize={21} color="#fff" />
                </div>
                <BsInfoCircle fontSize={17} color="#fff" />
              </div>
              <div>
                <p className="text-white font-light text-sm">
                  {shortenAddress(currentAccount)}
                </p>
                <p className="text-white font-semibold text-lg mt-1">
                  Ethereum
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="p-5 sm:w-96 w-full flex flex-col justify-start items-center blue-glassmorphism">
            <Input placeholder="Address To" name="addressTo" type="text" handleChange={handleChange} />
            <Input placeholder="Amount (ETH)" name="amount" type="number" handleChange={handleChange} />
            <Input placeholder="Keyword (Gif)" name="keyword" type="text" handleChange={handleChange} />
            <Input placeholder="Enter Message" name="message" type="text" handleChange={handleChange} />

            <div className="h-[1px] w-full bg-gray-400 my-2" />

            {isLoading
              ? <Loader />
              : (
                <button
                  type="button"
                  onClick={handleSubmit}
                  className="text-white w-full mt-2 border-[1px] p-2 border-[#3d4f7c] hover:bg-[#3d4f7c] rounded-full cursor-pointer"
                >
                  Send now
                </button>
              )}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Welcome;
```

App.jsx also includes Services, Transactions and footer. I believe there aren't mistakes there.

App.jsx

```
import { Footer, Welcome, Services, Transactions, Navbar } from './components';

function App() {
  return (    
    <div className="min-h-screen">
      <div className="gradient-bg-welcome">
        <Navbar />
        <Welcome /> 
        </div>
      <Services />
      <Transactions />
      <Footer />
    </div>  
  );
}

export default App;
```